# Server-side rendering with React.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, reactjs, semantic-ui, server-side-rendering

I cannot manage to render my semantic with Reactjs server side. It works without semantic, thus no problem with my react server side code.
Server crashes and gives the beginning lines of error:

```
/Users/isik/Dev/portfolio/reactjs-server-side-rendering/node_modules/semantic-ui-dropdown/index.js:3443
})( require("jquery"), window, document );
                       ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I have jquery insatlled with npm. And also lastly tried installing jsdom version jsdom@3.1.2. None worked.

I use [Recipes-Server-side rendering](http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/advanced-usage.html#server-side-rendering) in semantic-ui webpage.

the code I use for my server side component is as follows:

```
var React = require('react');
var jquery = require('jquery');
var dropdown = require('semantic-ui-dropdown');

// Can use JSX too
var Component = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
        $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
    },
    componentDidUpdate: function () {
        $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('refresh');
    },
    render: function(){
        return(
                <div className="ui selection dropdown">
                    <input type="hidden" name="gender"/>
                    <i className="dropdown icon"></i>
                    <div className="default text">Gender</div>
                    <div className="menu">
                        <div className="item" data-value="1">Male</div>
                        <div className="item" data-value="0">Female</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports.Component = Component;
```

Is that a general known issue with the server-side rendering with semantic-ui or I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    var dropdown = require('semantic-ui-dropdown');
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
},
```

I think that calling `require('semantic-ui-dropdown')` requires to have an existing `window` initialized in the DOM

And remove the actual `require('semantic-ui-dropdown')`  from the top of your file

Comment: Will that cause a conflict with the client side? There is a complete semantic-ui on the client side, the client side components use it and also the server side rendered components can use it as I have checked it.

Comment: Maybe. i can't say. It depends what use it. It could override an existing client side "semantic-ui" definition. May be the github post will give more answer on why it doesn't work :)

Comment: Without requiring jquery and individual semantic-ui components for server-side rendering as described in their above mentioned recipes, and without adding jquery using semantic-ui lifecycle methods I have successful results since on the client side where server side rendering goes into someplace I have the semantic-ui javascript and stylesheets linked to the index.html to have client side work. Can use it this way, as avoiding to use them on server side? Avoding jquery and semantic-ui stuff on server side, minding only proper semantic-ui class names.

Comment: Or the way you describe is a single way must. By my way of avoiding maybe cause React to re-render upon page load since the client side render component is different than the server side one, lacking methods like`dropdown()` etc, hence loosing the benefit of server side rendering, rendering use of it pointless.

Comment: I agree, It is important to keep both side rendering the same thing to keep the benefits of server side rendering

Comment: What is same in that context? Are two React Components that render same markup but having different methods same?